# I created a copy (B) of a Google Spreadsheet (A). Now the Google Form that used to feed A is feeding B

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Is there any way to change the settings of the Google Form so that it again feeds into the same worksheet of the same Google Spreadsheet (A) that it used to feed before I created the copy B?

The only option it gives me is to "create a new worksheet in an existing Spreadsheet". That doesn't work, though; it needs to be the -same- worksheet.

Also, who the heck thinks that it's a good idea to transfer links to a Google Form to the copy of a Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but it's true: form links to new Copy of spreadsheet.

Try this:

1. Go to created Copy
2. unlink form: `Form → Unlink form`
3. Try entering new values to your form: now the result goes to the first spreadsheet.