# How can I keep the link between a Google Form and a Google Sheet when I make copies of both?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form that is linked to a Google Sheet. I'm trying to share copies of both the Form and the Sheet with people, but when people make their copies, the link between the Form and the Sheet is broken. It's a flipped version of [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/92033/i-created-a-copy-b-of-a-google-spreadsheet-a-now-the-google-form-that-used?rq=1) and almost the same as this [unanswered question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/127677/copy-google-form-and-linked-sheet-preserving-existing-formulas-and-formatting).

Is there a way I can make it so that the copies are linked to each other and not the originals?

Comment: Welcome. Have you considered writing a script to enable a user to make a copy and link a spreadsheet?

Comment: No, I haven't. Is that the only way?

Comment: Would you please describe the characteristics of the linked spreadsheet that make it essential that a user make a copy of the linked spreadsheet rather than merely create a link to new spreadsheet.